# How to share secondary y-axis between subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

If you have multiple subplots containing a secondary y-axis (created using `twinx`), how can you share these secondary y-axes between the subplots? I want them to scale equally in an automatic way (so not set the y-limits afterwards by hand). For the primary y-axis, this is possible by using the keyword `sharey` in the call of `subplot`.

Below example shows my attempt, but it fails to share the secondary y-axis of both subplots. I'm using Matplotlib:

```py
ax = []

#create upper subplot
ax.append(subplot(211))
plot(rand(1) * rand(10),'r')

#create plot on secondary y-axis of upper subplot
ax.append(ax[0].twinx())
plot(10*rand(1) * rand(10),'b')

#create lower subplot and share y-axis with primary y-axis of upper subplot
ax.append(subplot(212, sharey = ax[0]))
plot(3*rand(1) * rand(10),'g')

#create plot on secondary y-axis of lower subplot
ax.append(ax[2].twinx())
#set twinxed axes as the current axes again,
#but now attempt to share the secondary y-axis
axes(ax[3], sharey = ax[1])
plot(10*rand(1) * rand(10),'y')
```

This gets me something like:

[image: Example of two subplots with failed sharing of secondary y-axis]

The reason I used the `axes()` function to set the shared y-axis is that `twinx` doesn't accept the `sharey` keyword.

I am using Python 3.2 on Win7 x64. Matplotlib version is 1.2.0rc2.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use `Axes.get_shared_y_axes()` like so:

```
from numpy.random import rand
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('gtkagg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create all axes we need
ax0 = plt.subplot(211)
ax1 = ax0.twinx()
ax2 = plt.subplot(212)
ax3 = ax2.twinx()

# share the secondary axes
ax1.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax1, ax3)

ax0.plot(rand(1) * rand(10),'r')
ax1.plot(10*rand(1) * rand(10),'b')
ax2.plot(3*rand(1) * rand(10),'g')
ax3.plot(10*rand(1) * rand(10),'y')
plt.show()
```

Here we're just joining the secondary axes together.

Comment: Yes, that helped me further, thanks. I also joined the primary y-axes so that they have a shared y-axis as well.

Comment: It doesn't work, the second twin scale get updated, but the second twin plot stays were it is.

Comment: Just to not have people get the wrong impression, the code as it is in this answer works fine.

Comment: The problem @mattia might have encountered: If you call a function like `ax1.set_ylim()` before `Axes.get_shared_y_axes().join()` then the two axes will NOT have the same scales (until you shift the axes interactively). Call `get_shared_y_axes().join()` first. BTW it works fine if you call it after calling `plot()`, etc.

Comment: `join` is deprecated in matplotlib 3.6.

Answer (score 2):

@dmcdougall's solution doesn't work anymore because `GrouperView` doesn't define `join` method anymore. However, it defines `joined`, so replacing `join` by `joined` in their code makes it run as expected.

However, a better solution is to use the method [recommended in the docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.6.0.html#groupers-from-get-shared-x-axes-get-shared-y-axes-will-be-immutable) to share y-axis: `Axes.sharey(Axes)`. A working example goes as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create all Axes
fig, (ax0, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, sharey=True)  # share the primary y-axis
ax1 = ax0.twinx()
ax3 = ax2.twinx()
ax1.sharey(ax3)                                 # share the secondary y-axis

ax0.plot(np.random.rand(10)*1., 'r')
ax1.plot(np.random.rand(10)*10, 'b')
ax2.plot(np.random.rand(10)*3., 'g')
ax3.plot(np.random.rand(10)*10, 'y')
```

which plots a figure like the following:

[image: result]