# Matplotlib tick dirrection for different sides of boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is the way to set direction for ticks at left side and right side of boxplot?
When I `x_or_y_axis.set_tick_params(direction='whatever')` it change direction for ticks at both sides of box:

```
  _______________        _______________
-|               |-     |-             -|
 |               |      |-             -|
-|               |-     |-             -|
 |               |      |-             -|
-|_______________|-  or |_______________|
```

But I need to:

```
  _______________         _______________
 |-              |-     -|             -|
 |               |       |              |
 |-              |-     -|             -|
 |               |       |              |
 |-______________|-  or -|_____________-|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create a twin axes using `ax.twinx()`, and then you can control the `yticks` on the two axes separately.

You will probably also want to then share the y axes between the two axes, so that the axes limits and ticks are the same between the two. We can use the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12924646/588071) to do that.

Here's a minimal example, modified from the [`boxplot` demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# fake up some data
spread = np.random.rand(50) * 100
center = np.ones(25) * 50
flier_high = np.random.rand(10) * 100 + 100
flier_low = np.random.rand(10) * -100
data = np.concatenate((spread, center, flier_high, flier_low), 0)

# Make the figure and axes
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

# Add you twin axes
ax2 = ax.twinx()

# Set the ticks to the outside on the right only
ax2.tick_params(axis='y',direction='out')

# Make sure the ticks and axes limits are shared between the left and right
ax.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax,ax2)

# basic boxplot
ax.boxplot(data)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thx a lot u are my saviour!