# Sharing two y axes on multiple matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

My goal is to have two rows and three columns of plots using matplotlib.  Each graph in the top row will contain two data series, and two y-axes.  I want to make the scales on each axis line up so that the corresponding data series are directly comparable.  Right now I have it so that the primary y-axis on each graph is aligned, but I can't get the secondary y-axes to align.  Here is my current code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


excel_file = 'test_data.xlsx'
sims = ['Sim 02', 'Sim 01',  'Sim 03']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = pd.read_excel(excel_file, skiprows=[0, 1, 2, 3], sheetname=None, header=1, index_col=[0, 1], skip_footer=10)
    plot_cols = len(sims)
    plot_rows = 2

    f, axes = plt.subplots(plot_rows, plot_cols, sharex='col', sharey='row')
    secondary_ax = []

    for i, sim in enumerate(sims):
        df = data[sim]
        modern = df.loc['Modern']
        traditional = df.loc['Traditional']
        axes[0][i].plot(modern.index, modern['Idle'])
        secondary_ax.append(axes[0][i].twinx())
        secondary_ax[i].plot(modern.index, modern['Work'])
        axes[1][i].bar(modern.index, modern['Result'])
        axes[0][i].set_xlim(12, 6)
        if i > 0:
            secondary_ax[0].get_shared_y_axes().join(secondary_ax[0], secondary_ax[i])

    # secondary_ax[0].get_shared_y_axes().join(x for x in secondary_ax)
    plt.show()
```

The solution I tried (Both the line in the if statement, and the last line before plt.show()) were solutions to similar questions, however it didn't resolve my issue.  Nothing breaks, the secondary axes just aren't aligned.

[image: Results of current code]

I also tried adding an extra row in the plt.subplots method and using twinx() to combined the first two rows, but it created an empty second row of plots none-the-less.

As a fall back I think I could manually check each axes for the maxes and mins, and loop through each to update manually, but I'd love to find a cleaner solution if one is out there, and anyone has any insight. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you not like about the produced plot? It looks fine to me. What does "align" refer to here? What should align to what exactly?

Comment: I want the secondary y-axes on the top row to align, so that they all share the same min and max, similar to the primary y-axes.

Comment: Ah I see. Do you have a [mcve] available for testing?

Comment: Not currently, I'll make the necessary tweaks and throw it on github in just a minute.

Comment: I can add the code in the question easily, but I'm not sure how to include the data source appropriately?  It's an excel file with three sheets that I'm importing with pandas.

Comment: Isn't this just a case of setting the y axis limits on each of the second y axes?

Comment: Are you saying that the code is dependent on your data file? I strongly doubt that. Either it is a general problem which occurs with just any data, in which case we don't want to have your actual data, or it is depending on only some of the data, in which case you may copy the relevant part of the data and produce a [mcve] from that part alone.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to imply that.  There's no dependence on the data, just didn't want to impose the hassle of recreating a test data set on you.


DavidG - That's currently my backup plan.  If possible I'd like to find a cleaner solution that doesn't involve manually checking and updating each secondary axis, but it's still on the table should it be needed.

Comment: There is also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919230/how-to-share-secondary-y-axis-between-subplots-in-matplotlib). Seems like it already has a working solution available.

Comment: Appreciate it! I had tried that answer before, but erroneously shared the axes after plotting instead of before as Colin pointed out below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to share the y axes before plotting your data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


# excel_file = 'test_data.xlsx'
sims = ['Sim 02', 'Sim 01',  'Sim 03']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #     data = pd.read_excel(excel_file, skiprows=[0, 1, 2, 3], sheetname=None, header=1, index_col=[0, 1], skip_footer=10)
    modern = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (100, 3)), columns=sims)
    traditional = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, 30, (100, 3)), columns=sims)
    traditional[sims[1]] = traditional[sims[1]] + 40
    traditional[sims[2]] = traditional[sims[2]] - 40
    data3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (100, 3)), columns=sims)

    plot_cols = len(sims)
    plot_rows = 2

    f, axes = plt.subplots(plot_rows, plot_cols, sharex='col', sharey='row', figsize=(30, 10))
    secondary_ax = []


    for i, sim in enumerate(sims):
        df = data[sim]
        modern_series = modern[sim]
        traditional_series = traditional[sim]
        idle = data3

        axes[0][i].plot(modern_series.index, modern_series)
        secondary_ax.append(axes[0][i].twinx())
        if i > 0:
            secondary_ax[0].get_shared_y_axes().join(secondary_ax[0], secondary_ax[i])

        secondary_ax[i].plot(traditional_series.index, traditional_series)
        #         axes[1][i].bar(data3.index, data3)
        axes[0][i].set_xlim(12, 6)

    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I reordered as you pointed out and now it's working perfectly.