# Is there a way to create a secondary y axis within a looped subplot figure using seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I have written the code successfully to loop through data and create subplots however, I want two of the data sets to be displayed on the y axis. Those are y and y1 or ax2. This code creates a secondary y axis however, it does not label the secondary y axis nor is their any data associated with it.

```
nrow = 4
ncol = 3
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrow, ncol, figsize=(17,17))
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=.1, right=1.5,top=1.75)
fig.delaxes(axes[3,2])

count = 0
for r in range(nrow):
  for c in range(ncol):

    x = dataobserved[count].index
    x1 = datamodeled[count].index
    y = dataobserved[count]['Average Q cfs']
    y1 = datamodeled[count]['QHistorical']
    y2 = dataobserved[count]['Total Generation Mwh']
    y3 = datamodeled[count]['Historical']

    sns.set_style("white")
    ax2 = ax.twinx()

    ax2 = sns.lineplot(x = x, y = y, color = "black", linestyle = '--', ax = axes[r,c])    
    ax2 = sns.lineplot(x = x1, y = y1, color = "blue", linestyle = '--', ax = axes[r,c]) 
    ax = sns.lineplot(x = x, y = y2, color = "black", ax = axes[r,c]) 
    ax = sns.lineplot(x = x1, y = y3, color = "blue", ax = axes[r,c]) 


    subplot_title = (str(ttl[count]))
    axes[r,c].set_title(subplot_title, size = 20)
    axes[r,c].legend(labels = ['Observed Outflow','Historical Baseline Outflow','Observed Generation','Historical Baseline Generation'], loc = "upper left")

    count+=1
  for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.set_xlabel('Water Year Week', fontsize = 15)
    ax.set_ylabel( 'Weekly Total Generation (Mwh)', fontsize = 15)
    ax2.set_ylabel('Weekly Average Outflow (cfs)')
    ax.set_xticks(range(1,52,10))
```

[example of two subplots produced from the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPEor.jpg)

I have reviewed [Share secondary y axis in looped seaborn plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53831482/share-secondary-y-axis-in-looped-seaborn-plots) but its not quite the same situation as the secondary y axis is not shared.

Comment: Although your input is unclear, several problems exist: 1) What is `ax2 = ax.twinx()` doing here? `ax` is not defined in the first loop. 2) You don't pass the secondary axes to the seaborn plot. 3) I wouldn't complicate things with rows and columns, just use `for count, ax in axes.flat:` - there you have both, the current axis and the count variable. 4) There is no need to defined `sns.set_style("white")`  in every loop. Place it outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no tater presented, I used sample data that I created appropriately and handled the subplots in a loop process. You have used the loop process twice, but by flattening the axes, you only need to do it once.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2021-01-01','2021-12-31',freq='1d'),
                   'y': np.random.randint(100,1000,365),
                   'y1': np.random.randint(200,2000,365),
                   'y2':np.random.rand(365),
                   'y3':np.random.rand(365)})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['Week'] = df['date'].dt.isocalendar().week
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month

fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,3, figsize=(17,17))
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=.1, right=1.5,top=1.75)

sns.set_style("white")

for i,ax in enumerate(axes.flat, start=1):
    dfs = df[df['month'] == i]
    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    sns.lineplot(data=dfs, x = 'Week', y = 'y', color = "black", linestyle = '--', estimator=None, ax=ax)    
    sns.lineplot(data=dfs, x = 'Week', y = 'y1', color = "blue", linestyle = '--', estimator=None, ax=ax) 
    sns.lineplot(data=dfs, x = 'Week', y = 'y2', color = "red", estimator=None, ax=ax2)
    sns.lineplot(data=dfs, x = 'Week', y = 'y3', color = "blue", estimator=None, ax=ax2)
    ax.set_title(i, size = 20)
    ax.legend(labels = ['y1','y2'], loc = "upper left")
    ax.set_xlabel('Water Year Week', fontsize = 15)
    ax.set_ylabel( 'Weekly Total Generation (Mwh)', fontsize = 15)
    ax2.set_ylabel('Weekly Average Outflow (cfs)')
    #ax.set_xticks(range(1,52,10))
```

[image]

Comment: The issue with supplying data is that I am looping through 11 sets of data each with two data frames. Your solution worked perfectly. I was truly stumped on this. The only other issue I have is combining the legend to support the two ax's but I think I can sort that out on my own. Thank you!